# Parsing of XML file from internal storage of tablet using pull parser

Tags: android

I am using below code to parse xml file from internal storage using pull parser but it closes application forcrefully please suggest me..!

```
FileInputStream fis = getApplicationContext().openFileInput("abc.xml");

XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(fis,null);

eventtype = xpp.getEventType();
```

file "abc.xml" stored in internal memory of tablet I was unable to parse it..
"abc.xml" file content is same as res/xml/abc.xml folder here parsing is done successfully.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, share logcat output.

Comment: Try giving the full path of file, instead of just name.

Comment: @S.D. - `openFileInput()` returns a `FileInputStream` from a file in the android application's internal private directory. No path is required. In fact, as far as I am aware, it is impossible to know the path at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask or run non UI Thread.